# Corporate CSR expenditure by firm

Tags: companies

Does anyone know whether there is a dataset containing annual CSR expenditures by major international companies?

I'm aware of the Prowess dataset, which provides this info for Indian firms. However, I'm looking for a dataset that covers major international companies, i.e., those listed on US exchanges.